# Inspect UI elements in Android

Tags: java, android

One of the most powerful tools coming from web development is the inspect elements capability in webkit/firebug that allows you to inspect the items in the DOM. Is there any equivalent for Android (non-web) development? I've been looking into MonkeyRunner but I'm not sure it has a way to describe the running app yet.

Comment: @leymannx That question and answers don't look like they help for native apps ("Android (non-web) development").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest thing is probably the [hierarchy viewer](http://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html) tool.