# Debugging on iOS safari

Tags: html, ios, css, debugging, safari

I'm making my portfolio website and I'm using pure HTML 5 no .js the about page doesn't work on iPhone and doesn't scroll everything together some of the elements positions are fixed and don't scroll. I don't own an iPhone but is there anyway to simulate the iOS on computer so I can debug the page? And is there such a tool like "inspect element" in chrome on the iOS safari? If not how can I debug and find how the browser is rendering wrong on the phone? Cause I validated my code and it's supposed to work, but its not!

Comment: Thanks, is there any alternative for windows, To simulate iOS? Or maybe any browser on android with iOS libraries and user agent?

Comment: Hi, I know you asked this question some time ago, but please take a look below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate iOS using **Xcode** and **Mac OS**.

And for the debug purpose there is no inspect element in Simulator. Yes you can take a help of **Accessibility Inspector**

In the Simulator >> Go to **Settings** >> **General**  >> **Accessibility**

Turn on **Accessibility Inspector** - This will help you to inspect different elements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something important to bear in mind is that because of Apple's policies, all browsers must use Safari’s layout engine to render pages, that means there are very few differences in rendering a page between Safari and other browsers on iOS.

There are two methods that you can use to debug a web page running on your iOS device on your using a browser on your Mac or Windows computer:

## 1. Debug using a Mac

If you have a Mac, you already have tools to live-inspect and debug web pages on your iOS device.

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

## 2. Debug using Windows

Xcode and MacOS are **not** the only way to debug websites running in a browser on OSX. There's a few ways:

**Telerik**

**WineRE**

I personally use Edge Inspect when I'm forced to use Windows.

**Adobe Edge Inspect**

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/edge-inspect/articles/browser-testing-across-devices-with-adobe-edge-inspect.html

Comment: Weinre works for debugging Safari in iOS, from Linux too. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718777/694469 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920560/694469