# webrtc error with mime.lookup

Tags: node.js, webrtc, mime

I tried webrtc demo on my PC.
but in demo step-04.
When I use npm install and node index.js,it shows 
"TypeError: mime.lookup is not a function".

even after I installed mime by typing "npm install mime"

How can I fix this and make the demo work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
use mime-type instead of mime. So, Install mime-types first:
    npm install mime-types
then make change in your code:
    var mime=require('mime-types');
```

Comment: I would like to add that the *mime* variable should be changed in node-static.js (./node_modules/node-static/lib/node-static.js). I'm also a beginner at node.js and it took me a little while to find out :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same issue with step 4. 
You can changing the node-static version from `0.7.7` to `0.7.10` in **package.json** and rerunning `npm install`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "node-static": "0.7.10",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0" }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have a folder "node modules" in your root directory,delete that and type `npm cache clear` and then type `npm install`.this should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting node_modules and running `npm i` and `npm start`.

If the problem still exists try doing `npm update --legacy-peer-deps` and rerun your application.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but then try to use mime ~1.2.7 and i think this will work fine.
just change your version of mime in package.json file and install it.

Answer (score 0):

change mime.lookup(type) to mime.getType(type)

Answer (score 0):

As @HRISHABH RAJ mentioned you want to reference `mime-type` instead of `mime` however you should check your `node_modules` folder first to see if the package is already installed.